# What books i should read side by side Apostol Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I ma currently reading Mathematical Analysis by Tom M. Apostol. I ma currently in the third chaptee Elements of Point Set Topology. While reading this nad doing the exercises i understood that i am getting stuck at so many places. Can you tell me some books which i should read along with apostol so thta i understand the theory better. If there is a bok which explains the theory of apostol in more wasy way tell me that also

Comment: I'm sure you will appreciate Real Analysis by Carothers if you've had at least a prior elementary course in analysis.

Comment: Whatever you read, make sure you do the exercises. You learn mathematics by doing, not by watching it done.